# Logging out from Google external service

Tags: cookies, oauth, logout

I have a "problem".

I use in my site a login/logout external service of Google.

If I inspect the resources, expecially the cookies, I see that when I logout from the site, the cookie related is deleted.

But if I press the back button of the browser the cookie is recreated.....

the external service og Google automatically relog in the user, without any authentication process...

How can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using OAuth2?

Comment: I used OAuth. But I read that it's a problem of Google services. From the client side the cookie is deleted, but from the service side informations are stored and recreated again without control on the same machine. So I think the solutions are services like the new Mozilla Persona http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/persona/

Comment: In OAuth2 you can revoke a token, which has exactly the effect you're looking for. Just send a revoke request to the server and the token becomes useless.

Comment: Great! Put this like an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is trustworthy solution for logging out of Google and your RP.

Just call this URI

https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://www.yourapp.com

it will logout of google and redirect back to your app. Thanks!

Soon I will post my logout solution for windows live and facebook.com STS.

Please vote and mark as answer

Comment: The user's already accepted an answer that logs someone out by revoking the OAuth token. Could you add some explanation to explain why doing it this way might be better?

Comment: By revoking the oAuth token does not actually logs your out of Google in you browser. You may test in by opening the account.google.com in the another tab of same browser session. It never worked for me and this is a security risk. I would recommend to go for what I had suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

In OAuth2 you can revoke a token, which has exactly the effect you're looking for. Send a revoke request to the server and the token becomes useless.

Just do a GET request to this URL:

```
'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + accessToken
```

The browser will still be logged in to Google, which may be a concern in some situations, but your application is logged out.